# how to set default value for multi select field e.g specificcountry?

Tags: magento2, configuration, system.xml

I've a field in system.xml

```
    <field id="specificcountry" translate="label" type="multiselect" sortOrder="40" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
    <label>Ship to Specific Countries</label>
<source_model>Magento\Directory\Model\Config\Source\Country</source_model>
    </field>
```

but how can i set the default value in config.xml, what is the syntax should be? like the following?

```
<default>
    <carriers>
        <mymodule>
             <specificcountry>HK,US,AU</specificcountry>
        </mymodule>
    </carriers>
</default>
```

Comment: you need three default values?

Comment: looks like you are doing it right. maybe you need to clear the cache or make sure that the tag under `carriers` is ok.

Comment: I can remember I run into the same issue before until I found out that there is already a value saved in my database which is overriding the default config settings. Try to remove it from the database and load again it will select all the defined default values